# Check if cells are empty

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am doing a macro that checks whether cells are empty or full. But is there any fast way to check if only one cell out of three, in a row, is not empty?

my code:

```
 LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.row = LastRow + 1
     If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
     If IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 1)) = False And IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 1)) = False And IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 3))=False  And IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 4))=False Then
      MsgBox "None empty empty"
    ElseIf IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 1)) = True And IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 2)) = True And IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 3)) = True And IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 4)) = True  Then
        MsgBox "All empty"
      End If
     End If
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
```

But is there a way to check if only one two or three out of 4 cells are not empty?

I am looking for. In my code i would like it to check the following:
 `If IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 1)) = False And IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 1)) = False And IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 3))=True And IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 4))=True Then MsgBox "2 empty"`

So if 2 are empty and two are not it shpuld always check it. I dont want to write a lot of if statements that is why i am asking if there is any faster way-

Comment: I am looking for. In my code i would like it to check the following: If IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 1)) = False And IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 1)) = False And IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 3))=True And IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 4))=True Then MsgBox "2 empty" So if 2 are empty and two are not it shpuld always check it. I dont want to write a lot of if statements that is why i am asking if there is any faster way-

Answer (score 3):

For a specific set of cells, **A1** through **D1**

One way:

```
Sub EmptyCounter()
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
   Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
   Set rng = Range("A1:D1")

   MsgBox "There are " & 4 - wf.CountA(rng) & " empties"
End Sub
```

Here we explicitly ignore the case of Null strings.

Comment: Thank you but not exactly what I am looking for. In my code i would like it to check the following:

If IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 1)) = False And IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 1)) = False And IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 3))=True  And IsEmpty(Cells(ActiveCell.row, 4))=True Then
      MsgBox "2 empty"

So if 2 are empty and two are not it shpuld always check it. I dont want to write a lot of if statements that is why i am asking if there is any faster way-

Comment: @jojou96 I think Gary's code does do what you want?

Comment: Yes sorry  my bad. How can i do the range so it counts A1:D50 to last row, so it only checks every row and not the whole range.

Answer (score 0):

As per your sample code your objective is to identify when:

1. All cells 4 first cells in row are empty or
2. All cells 4 first cells in row are not empty
3. Rows with a mix of empty and not empty cells are ignored

Suggest the use of objects, also to marked (either with color or with a value in an adjacent cell) the cells found. 
Below you have two sets of codes one showing a message for each row with full values or totally empty (as you have now) and also a sample with the suggestion of coloring the resulting cells.

```
Rem Code showing messages
Sub Wsh_MarkCellsEmptyAndNotEmpty_Msg()
Dim RngTrg As Range
Dim lRowLast As Long
Dim vCellsValue As Variant
Dim lRow As Long
Dim bNoneEmpty As Byte
Dim b As Byte

    Rem No changes to your method for finding last row
    lRowLast = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Rem Set Target Range
    Set RngTrg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1), Cells(lRowLast, 4))

    For lRow = 1 To lRowLast
        With RngTrg.Rows(lRow)

            Rem To Select cells [NOT RECOMMENDED PRACTICE]
            Rem Instead suggest to marked cells found
            .Select

            Rem Initiate Variables
            bNoneEmpty = 0
            vCellsValue = Empty

            Rem Look into cells values
            For b = 1 To 4
                If .Cells(b).Value <> Empty Then bNoneEmpty = 1 + bNoneEmpty
                vCellsValue = vCellsValue & .Cells(b).Value2
            Next

            Rem Show Message with Results
            If vCellsValue = Empty Then
                MsgBox "All Cells are empty"
            ElseIf bNoneEmpty = 4 Then
                MsgBox "None Cell is empty"
            End If

    End With: Next

End Sub

Rem Code marking cells with color (user friendly)
Sub Wsh_MarkCellsEmptyAndNotEmpty_Color()
Dim RngTrg As Range
Dim lRowLast As Long
Dim vCellsValue As Variant
Dim lRow As Long
Dim bNoneEmpty As Byte
Dim b As Byte

    Rem No changes to your method for finding last row
    lRowLast = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Rem Set Target Range
    Set RngTrg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1), Cells(lRowLast, 4))

    Rem To Clear Cells Colors if marking with colors cells found
    RngTrg.Interior.Pattern = xlNone

    For lRow = 1 To lRowLast
        With RngTrg.Rows(lRow)

            Rem Initiate Variables
            bNoneEmpty = 0
            vCellsValue = Empty

            Rem Look into cells values
            For b = 1 To 4
                If .Cells(b).Value <> Empty Then bNoneEmpty = 1 + bNoneEmpty
                vCellsValue = vCellsValue & .Cells(b).Value2
            Next

            Rem Mark Resulting cells
            If vCellsValue = Empty Then
                Rem Colors Empty Cells in Red
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)
            ElseIf bNoneEmpty = 4 Then
                Rem Colors No Empty Cells in Green
                .Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
            End If

    End With: Next
End Sub
```